# Float 32 Array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

In javascript I have the following arrays for a CPU buffer:

```
var nVerts = this.m_countVertices;
this.m_bindPositions = new Float32Array(nVerts * 3);
this.m_bindNormals = new Float32Array(nVerts * 3);
this.m_deformedPositions = new Float32Array(nVerts * 3);
```

What do you recommend to use in objective-c, instead of Float32Array. Would an NSArray be sufficient?

Thanks

Comment: Either a conventional `float[]` C array or an NSArray of NSNumbers.

Comment: the `NSArray` is robust stuff, therefore much slower than working with direct `float`s or `double`s. my private experience says it is 10 times slower, which is still not relevant in case of 20.000 (twenty-thousand) `NSNumber` objects in an `NSArray`. so, I encourage you to use `NSArray`, because it is more convenient container if you even like to filter or sort the items.

Comment: @holex - Except with NSArray you have to mess with NSNumber rather than storing the values directly into the array.

Comment: @HotLicks, yes, that is what I've mentioned exactly.

Comment: @holex - Not just speed, but additional operations and additional clutter, with accompanying increase in the likelihood of a coding error.

Comment: @HotLicks, yes, that what I've **really** mentioned exactly. do you want to enhance it?

Comment: I'm saying that the *NSArray* increases the number of operations and the likelihood of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Xcode where `Float32` is defined, you should probably just:

```
Float32* m_bindPositions = (Float32*)malloc( (nVerts * 3) * sizeof(Float32));
```

Then it should be a chunk of memory analogous to the code you've shown.  Just don't forget to

```
free(m_bindPositions)
```

to release the memory when you're done with it.